# AngularUI - Google Maps - Remove marker

Tags: google-maps, angularjs, angular-ui

I am using AngularUI Google Maps directive in this way:

**UpdateData.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="marker in myMarkers" ui-map-marker="myMarkers[$index]"></div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Situación</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div id="map_canvas" ui-map="model.myMap" class="map" ui-event="{'map-click': 'addMarker($event)'}" ui-options="mapOptions"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UpdateController**

```
if (!$scope.myMarkers) {
    $scope.myMarkers = [];
}

if (!$scope.myMap) {
    $scope.model = {
        myMap: undefined
    };
}

$scope.mapOptions = {
    center : new google.maps.LatLng(35.784, -78.670),
    zoom : 15,
    mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

$scope.addMarker = function($event) {
    $scope.myMarkers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map : $scope.model.myMap,
        position : $event.latLng
    }));

    $scope.event.lat = $event.latLng.lat();
    $scope.event.lng = $event.latLng.lng();
};
```

I can add new markers and the map is updated successfully by I can't remove them. What I do is the following:

```
$scope.myMarkers.splice(0, $scope.myMarkers.length);
```

`myMarkers` array gets empty but the map still contains removed markers. It seems that `myMarkers` array and map are synchronized when pushing new markers to `myMarkers` array but not when `myMarkers` array is cleared.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `myMarker.setMap(null)`.

You still have to use the Google Maps API to do everything, there's not much magic involved.  The only reason `ui-map-marker` is a directive is so you can easily hook up DOM events to your markers

Answer (score 7):

I answer to myself. Before executing this line

```
$scope.myMarkers.splice(0, $scope.myMarkers.length);
```

This should be done:

```
angular.forEach($scope.myMarkers, function(marker) {
    marker.setMap(null);
});
```

Comment: hello I have the same problem, and it didn't work for me because i'm not `using new google.maps.Marker({
        map : $scope.model.myMap,
        position : $event.latLng
    })` to add a marker but a customise function to add markers with customise icon and info.

do you have an idea how to deal with this ?